# Helm install time out

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Running helm install for my chart gives my time out error. I have no idea why. Running this in a simple aws instance, no firewall or anything like that. I worked previously and suddenly stopped working.

```
# helm install xxxx-services-1 chart/ --values chart/values.yaml
Error: failed pre-install: timed out waiting for the condition
```

already tried:

1. restarting kubernetes
2. rebooting the machine
3. kubeadm reset & kubeadm init

Update:

1. using helm 3
2. when I run with --debug, these are last lines, and it's stuck there:

   client.go:463: [debug] Watching for changes to Job xxxx-services-1-ingress-nginx-admission-create with timeout of 5m0s

   client.go:491: [debug] Add/Modify event for xxxx-services-1-ingress-nginx-admission-create: ADDED

   client.go:530: [debug] xxxx-services-1-ingress-nginx-admission-create: Jobs active: 0, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
   client.go:491: [debug] Add/Modify event for xxxx-services-1-ingress-nginx-admission-create: MODIFIED

   client.go:530: [debug] xxxxx-services-1-ingress-nginx-admission-create: Jobs active: 1, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
3. when i do `kubectl get jobs` i did see an active job, i deleted it, ran the install again - still same result

Comment: Add `--debug` to your helm command and post the output.

Comment: Using helm2 or helm3?

Comment: Check if you have any failed kubernetes job in the namespace you are trying to install ? If yes remove the job and try to install again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue, I didn't taint my master node...

`kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-`

I can't believe how much time I spent on this little thing...

Comment: Isn't this _removing_ the taint from the master node rather than tainting it, because of the `-` sign at the end? If a node is tainted it means pods can't be scheduled onto it. It looks like this is _allowing_ pods to be scheduled onto the master node, which may have happened to fix your issue, but will result in incorrect setup

Answer (score 1):

For this type of issue, you may have a pod that's failing to start correctly. Use `kubectl describe pod [failing_pod_name]` to get a clear indication of what's causing the issue. The issue will be given at the bottom of the output of `kubectl describe ...`

(Also, adding `--debug` at the end of your `helm install` command can show some additional detail)